# have multiple tooltips/popups show neatly stacked in the windows systray area, similar to messenger/anti-virus notifications

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, notifyicon, systray

I am working on a program that monitors several things such as incomming messages, faxes, calendar items and alerts etc.

This program is normaly in the systray.

What i want to accomplish is to have multiple tooltips or forms pop up, one for every notification. When there are multiple messages to show, i want to be able to have them stack on top of each other neatly. Or maybe allow the user to have a couple of diffrent view types.

Can anyone here help me with showing multiple tooltips at once and how i can arrange them on the screen?

It can also be a form or something else, key is having multiple events at once and beeing able to arrange them.

Thansk in advance,
Mike

Comment: take a look here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=320639
Might guide you in the right direction

Comment: What are you using? ASP.NET, WPF, Winforms...? Pls tag the question.

Comment: You're not going to get an answer until you specify WPF or Winforms (noticed you said it's in the systray, so no ASP.NET). I'm voting to close because in it's current form it can't be answered.

Comment: Currecntly i am using Winforms sorry for not beeing specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place them into an object, you'll probably want to use either `Queue<T>` or `Stack<T>` to hold them. If you need to use them with threads `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or `ConcurrentStack<T>`. You'll want to make them Observable if dealing with bindings or use `ObservableCollection<T>` if you don't care about ordering and FIFO/FILO.

Other than that you'll need to give us some more information about what you are currently using.

For WPF: http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon

Comment: This wpf-notifyicon looks very nice! Is it able to show more then one tooltip at once?  That's the issue i am realy trying to figure out. Like for example if you have msn and someone logs in, it will pop up a tooltip saying xxxx logged in. but when 2 people log in at the same time, the second tooltip will pop up right above the first one, same for the third etc. that functionality is what i am trying to get.

Comment: You should be able to modify the popup to look like that (have one popup window with multiple internal "popups"), or stack itself.

Comment: I eventualy solved it another way. But i did wanted to select this as answer since it was the most accurate. Thx all for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

The answer in below SO question might help you and give the direction, but you would still need to customize that code to **hook up for event notifications**:
[Creating a Popup Balloon like Windows Messenger or AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413656/creating-a-popup-balloon-like-windows-messenger-or-avg)

Additional information on ballon tip and its issues:
http://www.csharp411.com/notifyiconshowballoontip-issues/

MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065.aspx

Comment: I have looked at all suggestions from everyone. Most are very nice and cool looking. Just none of them seems to support more then 1 popup at the same time. only Growl does it, but you cannot implement that.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I would look into something called Growl:

- http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx

You might want to check this page for a quick visual overview of what it offers:

- http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/displays.aspx

Comment: Growl looks realy nice, and does do everything i want. But i need this functionality inside my own application. Growl (as far as i can see) will only let you sent alerts to their application.