# c# notifications in taskbar windows7

Tags: c#, notifications, taskbar

I want to write a simple program in c# winforms, that shows a notifications to users (in task bar windows 7 or 10) in a constant time (for example in 13:00 and 21:00).

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Popup Balloon like Windows Messenger or AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413656/creating-a-popup-balloon-like-windows-messenger-or-avg)

Comment: jayv where duplicate? my question is different.
i don't need use buttons. but need sys.date.

Comment: The answer to that question shows how to use NotifyIcon, which, I think is what you are asking for as well

Answer (score 1):

Basically if `DateTime.Now` (current hour) equals a specific hour, show the notify icon.

You should run this code inside of a timer/task.

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 13 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 00 || DateTime.Now.Hour == 21 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 00)
{
    var notification = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon()
    {
        Visible = true,
        Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information,
        BalloonTipText = "This is my notify icon",
    };
    notification.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
}
```

Comment: to which event of a form or other component can this code be added in order to trigger it in real time?

Comment: @MarkKovak In a timer or a task.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Start();

    }
    int lastNotify = 0;
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now.Hour == 16 && lastNotify != 16) || (DateTime.Now.Hour == 21 && lastNotify != 21))
        {
            this.notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Whatever";
            this.notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Title";
            this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            this.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3);

            lastNotify = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        }
    }
```